# Comparing numeric values in ENUM to parameters

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum which represents a CardRank, in descending order.

```
    public enum Position
    {
        ACE('A'), KING('K'), QUEEN('Q'), JACK('J'),
        TEN('T'), NINE('9'), EIGHT('8'), SEVEN('7'),
        SIX('6'), FIVE('5'), FOUR('4'), TREY('3'), DEUCE('2');

        private char symbol;

        private Position(char symbol)
        {
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }

        public char getSymbol()
        {
            return this.symbol;
        }
    }
```

I need to compare **the parameter given to the method to the values assigned to each enum element**. When the given card parameter has a lower rank, this method should return false, and when the given parameter has an equal or higher rank it should return true.

**TEST** to make this question more clear.

```
    @Test
    void testOrder() {
        position = Position.TEN;
        assertFalse(position.isPreceding(Position.ACE));
        assertFalse(position.isPreceding(Position.KING));
        assertFalse(position.isPreceding(Position.QUEEN));
        assertTrue(position.isPreceding(Position.NINE));

        position = Position.TREY;
        assertFalse(position.isPreceding(Position.FOUR));
        assertFalse(position.isPreceding(Position.FIVE));
        assertFalse(position.isPreceding(Position.SIX));
        assertTrue(position.isPreceding(Position.DEUCE));

        position = Position.KING;
        assertTrue(position.isPreceding(Position.QUEEN));
        assertTrue(position.isPreceding(Position.NINE));
        assertTrue(position.isPreceding(Position.DEUCE));
    }
```

I found that `compareTo()` or `ordinal()` methods appear the way to go, but I'm having trouble converting the String parameter to numbers.

This is my latest attempt:

```
    public boolean isOrdered (Position position) {
        for (Position p : values()) {
            if (position.compareTo(p) >=0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Managed to solve it.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I adapted the question to make it easier to follow/explain but I forgot about CardRank (now remained to Position).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `compareTo()` method that is part of every `enum` <sup>**1**</sup>.

```java
public boolean isPreceding(Position position) {
    return this.compareTo(position) < 0;
}
```

---

It is not very clear what is meant by *"converting the String parameter to numbers:*, no `String` is not being used in the given code examples. To get the `enum` with a given name, its `valueOf()` method can be used <sup>**2**</sup>.

```java
// this method is not really needed, call `valueOf()` directly
public static Position getForName(String name) {
    // eventually use 'name.toUpperCase()'
    return Position.valueOf(name);
}
```

Now it is easy to get the ordinal having the name of the enum:

```java
public static int ordinalForName(String name) {
    // use <code>name.toUpperCase()</code> below, if needed 
    return Position.valueOf(name).ordinal();
}
```

---

To get an `enum` element, given its `Symbol`, I would use a static `Map` mapping each `Symbol` to its element:

```java
private static final Map<Character, Position> positions = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
    Arrays.stream(values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Position::getSymbol, Function.identity()))
    );
    
public static Position getForSymPosition(char symbol) {
    return positions.get(symbol);
}
```

---

---

<sup>The methods are intended to be added to the `enum` class.</sup>

**1** - see documentation of its superclass: [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E))
**2** - `valueOf()` is added to all enums ass described in [JLS 8.9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3-100-E)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the order:

```
public enum Position
{
    ACE('A', 14), KING('K', 13), QUEEN('Q', 12), JACK('J', 11),
    TEN('T', 10), NINE('9', 9), EIGHT('8', 8), SEVEN('7', 7),
    SIX('6', 6), FIVE('5', 5), FOUR('4', 4), TREY('3', 3), DEUCE('2', 2);

    private char symbol;
    private int order;

    private Position(char symbol, int order)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.order = order;
    }

    public char getSymbol()
    {
        return this.symbol;
    }

    public boolean isPreceding (Position position) {
       return this.order < position.order;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't seem to pass the tests. (Expected: false, actual: true). Also, the UML doesn't mention anything about "order". (but thanks)

Comment: UML? is this a homework?

Comment: if by "isPreceding" you mean syntactic preceding, you can change the order numbers to match the syntactic order. If "isPreceding" is semantically consistent with a deck game, your test case is wrong.